# How to find nodes before a given node with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am developing a Roslyn analyzer to detect the use of a specific method, `method1`. I want to allow the use of this method in `for` and `while` loops, and create an issue in all other cases in the code.

How can I do that? The code I developed detects `method1` everywhere. I want now each time I find the function, to check if it's in a loop or not, and generate an error only if it is not in a loop.

Comment: But what is the level of *nesting* that you want to allow? How far down the call stack should your analyzer go? What if you have a call chain `methodN`->`method2`->`method1` and the loop that calls this chain is in `methodN`? Also, think about the fact that the structure of your code at runtime and at compile time is not the same. What if you pass `method1` as a delegate to another method that wraps it in a loop, at runtime? Like LINQ uses `Func`, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method call will be a descendant of the loop declaration if it is inside it. You can access the [`Ancestors`](http://www.coderesx.com/roslyn/html/A6B74233.htm) property of any `SyntaxNode`. Start going up among the ancestors of the `MethodInvocation` node you detected until you hit a loop or a member declaration.

If you hit a loop (`ForStatementSyntax` or `WhileStatementSyntax`) then you are good.
If you hit a `MemberDeclarationSyntax` node that means you have reached the start of whatever block in which your `method1` is being called and should probably throw an error.

At this point, your immediate problem is *mostly* solved, and you have to decide how many corner cases you want to cover. What if it is called from a lambda expression? What if a method that calls `method1` is called from a loop? Or from a recursive method?

You can detect all these cases but you have to decide if it is worth the effort.